# Nginx HTTP Proxying link between location

Tags: nginx, proxy

Let say that I have a domain test.com. And Nginx serving several apps.
How can I do:

- test.com/match/here - this will be the request

to be processed by nginx as:

- test.com/new/prefix/match/here

Is it possible with nginx

```
#server context

location /match/here {
    proxy_pass http://example.com/new/prefix;
}
location /app {
    ...
}
. . .
```

The other question is how one location can refirect to another location by nginx configuration only?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make nginx process request to `test.com/match/here` from location `test.com/new/prefix/match/here`, you need to do this:

```
location ~ /match/here(.*) {
    rewrite ^ /new/prefix/match/here$1 last;
}
```

`proxy_pass` is used when you want to pass the request to another program that will process the request. From your question it looks like that you only want to change the request URI, which is done with the above entry.

For further information on the `rewrite` directive, have a look at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html